# R - Parsing JSON code with multiple levels

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I'm trying to parse JSON using R. Using `fromJSON()` in the jsonlite package gets me most of the way there. But what's the most efficient way build out a data frame when the json has multiple levels?

Say I have this json code:

```
[
   {
      "id":"0001",
      "type":"donut",
      "batters":{
         "batter":[
            {
               "id":"1001",
               "type":"Regular"
            },
            {
               "id":"1002",
               "type":"Chocolate"
            },
            {
               "id":"1003",
               "type":"Blueberry"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I read it in and parse using `fromJSON`

```
json <- readLines(...)
out <- fromJSON(json)
```

That gets me a data frame with 1 observation and 3 variables. The last variable is a list with all the "batter" values.

I want to build this out to get 3 observations with 4 variables.

```
id     type     batter.id     batter.type
0001   donut    1001          Regular
0001   donut    1002          Chocolate
0001   donut    1003          Blueberry
```

Can I do this with directly while parsing the json code? Or do I need to build out the table using something like `unlist`? (If so, how would this be done efficiently using something like `unlist`?)

Comment: You've already sorted it more cleanly, but you could use `unlist` in a slightly more roundabout way - `data.frame(lapply(fromJSON(txt, flatten=TRUE), unlist, rec=FALSE))` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit more digging, I found `unnest` in tidyr.

```
unnest(out, batter, names_sep = ".")
```